# Upper and lowercase of a word in the \section heading

Tags: sectioning, formatting, capitalization

I'm using the `\section` command and wanted to change just two letters of a word to be in lowercase. How can I accomplish this? I have tried using `\small` command but it will not change it.

```
\section{Writing and Reading Using \small{rs}EGFP's}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Are you looking to lowercase a part of a word, or to render it smaller than the surroundings? The command `\small` affects the size of the type, not whether the subsequent word is set in lowercase (or uppercase).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might be looking for `\MakeLowercase`:

```
\section{Writing and Reading Using \MakeLowercase{rs}EGFP's}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I have a feeling that you're looking to typeset a part of the section header *smaller* than its surroundings. However, if you are in fact looking to force some characters to be typeset in uppercase or lowercase, do see @GonzaloMedina's answer for a demonstration of the use of the command `\MakeLowercase` (and its twin, `\MakeUppercase`).

By the way, the command `\small` does not take an argument but affects all subsequent material until the end of the "group" that contains the `\small` command is reached. Thus, don't write `\small{rs}` but, rather, `{\small rs}`. Because the relative font size used in section headings is `\Large`, which is two steps up from `\normalsize`, and because `\small` is one step smaller than `\normalsize`, use of the command `\small` results in text in the section header that's three (relative) steps smaller than the surroundings.

If you're looking to reduce the font size by a number of steps without needing to know what the absolute font size currently in use may be, you could use the `relsize` package and its `\smaller` and `\relsize{-2}` commands. The following MWE shows how this may be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\section*{Writing and Reading using rsEGFPs}             % no change in size
\section*{Writing and Reading using {\smaller rs}EGFPs}  % 1 step smaller
\section*{Writing and Reading using {\relsize{-2}rs}EGFP's} % 2 steps smaller
\section*{Writing and Reading using {\small rs}EGFPs}    % 3 steps smaller
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want `\lowercase{}` to force the text to remain in lowercase, so this would be:

```
\section{Writing and Reading Using \lowercase{rs}EGFP's}
```

Comment: `\lowercase` comes from TeX and might not always behave well in LaTeX documents: compare `\lowercase{\OE}`
and `\MakeLowercase{\OE}`.

Comment: The output is identical for me.

Comment: Using `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\lowercase{\OE} and \MakeLowercase{\OE}
\end{document}` you'll see that `\lowercase` has no effect, whereas `\MakeLowercase` produces the desired output.

Comment: ok, you are right; but inside an `\MakeUppercase` neither of them work on `\OE`: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \MakeUppercase{\lowercase{\OE} and  \MakeLowercase{\OE}} \end{document}`.