# How to get lower-case letters in a page header

Tags: header-footer

In latex when we write section include the chapter, on the top of pages it write as a capital letter, for example

`\section{Solution in R^{n}}`,
 on the top write
**SOLUTION IN R^N,**
my question is, who we control it especially I want to wrote " R^n " instead " R^N "

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) please add 
a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to understand your problem. See also how [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) in your question.

Comment: Check this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4761/23688

Comment: BTW, your code `\section{Solution in R^{n}}` is wrong (_Missing $ inserted_). Perhaps it must be `\section{Solution in $R^{n}$}` ?

Comment: dear Fran, even with '$ R^{n} $' not work, also i try to use the Petr Marek, but its another things, i need just how i write the section title i get the same things in the top of the page

Comment: By *top of the page*, do you mean headers? If so are you using `fancyhdr`?

Comment: the ams document classes (`amsart` et al.) have the command `\uppercasenonmath` that exempts all math from uppercasing, used usually for formatting running heads.  unfortunately, the code is rather complex, and i have been unsuccessful in extracting just the relevant bits to provide a "quick fix".  however, someone else might be able to sort it out and pull it into a useful package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lipsum}
\section{S\lowercase{olution in} $R^{\lowercase{n}}$}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies for the necromancy, but according to some of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66132/upper-and-lowercase-of-a-word-in-the-section-heading) would `MakeLowercase` be a better option?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a general solution, but for this particular example, the following will work. Define the command `\Rn` at the preamble as:

```
\newcommand{\Rn}{$R^n$}
```

and use it when required in your document as `\Rn{}`, except at sections or chapters, where you have to `\protect` it to prevent the uppercase conversion:

```
\section{Solution in \protect\Rn}
```

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\Rn{$R^{n}$}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lipsum}
\section{Solution in \protect\Rn{}}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

And these are some exceprts of the resulting pdf, showing the relevant parts:

Table of contents:

[image: Table of contents]

Section title:

[image: Sections]

Page header:

[image: Headers]