# Exclude word from uppercase in section heading

Tags: sectioning, acm, acmart

Similarly to the thread [Upper and lowercase of a word in the \section heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66132/upper-and-lowercase-of-a-word-in-the-section-heading)
, I want to disable uppercase for a single word. However, the word should not be in lowercase, but printed as written.

I'm using the ACM sigconf template (`\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`) wherein all section titles are uppercase by default. I want to be able adding the chapter's author right-aligned, next to the chapter's title, as `(Authorname)` instead of currently `(AUTHORNAME)`:

[image]

Preamble:

```
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{\hfill\textcolor{gray}{\normalfont{(#1})}}
```

Document Environment:

```
\section{Introduction \chapterAuthor{Authorname}}
```

Comment: you have provided no example to test but I assume `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}` and `\NoCaseChage{Authorname}` would work.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that a MWE is not required here. I can confirm that your solution works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Funny thing: One can read (at least partially) what you tried to make unreadable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided no example to test but I assume (apparently correctly :-) that

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

and

```
\NoCaseChange{Authorname}
```

would work in your case.